# Model Causing scaffolding to crash

Tags: visual-studio-2017

For some reason the following model is causing the scaffolding templates to crash it is not giving me an error just the visual studio 2017 dialog stooped responding and then crashes out.

It produces no errors and I checked the event log couldnt see anything linking to scafollding

Also are their any scaffolding templates that output Bootstrap comp table forms ?.

```
 public class basketheader

{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string emailBasket { get; set; }
    public decimal basketTotal { get; set; }
    public int currency { get; set; } 
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDated { get; set; }
    public bool isSaved { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }   
    public int basketSessionId { get; set; }     

    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }
    public BasketStatus BasketStatusSetting { get; set; }
    public enum BasketStatus
    {
        Basket=0,
        Order = 1,
        Abandon=2,
        FailedPayment=3,
        Discarded=4
    }
}
```

Basket Lines

```
public class basketlines

    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public int basketId { get; set; }
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }

        public int qty { get; set; }

        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public decimal lineTotal {get;set;}

        public decimal Total { get { return qty * price; } }


        public bool isVisible { get; set; }

        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }


        public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

    }
```

I managed to find an error in my event viewer but not sure if it related to scafoolding directly

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 15.0.26430.16, time stamp: 0x5968f055
Faulting module name: PresentationCore.ni.dll, version: 4.7.2102.0, time stamp: 0x5937170a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00245bdb
Faulting process id: 0xaf0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d33538be99ac24
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\e455d647c69dde661983d913460fef16\PresentationCore.ni.dll
Report Id: a9a59056-e157-4f3c-a1b2-23a695355c2b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the solution? Restart VS?

Comment: The solution builds fine and I have cleaned it yes first thing I did.

Comment: Try restarting your machine and delete everything from the %temp% folder

Comment: have done this no effect going re install lattest version as I am version behind in studio at mo

Comment: For anyone else having issues it was an issue with previous release I also Found I could install update from online installer so created a new layout using the following command to update my visual studio 

vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2017 --lang en-US